# Minecraft Crashes After Mod Installation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am currently using the 1.5.2 version, because I honestly do not want to update for a bit longer as well as some of the mods don't go past 1.5. With Having said that minecraft seems to crash after I installed a series of mods which are listed in the report, the reason I am asking is because I cannot seem to find the error in the report here is the crash report....

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

Time: 10/18/14 11:30 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

cpw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: manager
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:142)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:515)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:160)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:411)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftAppletImpl.func_71384_a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:733)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: manager
    at ic2.core.IC2.load(IC2.java:814)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:494)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:314)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:98)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:514)
    ... 5 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_55, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 376376784 bytes (358 MB) / 519110656 bytes (495 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v7.51 FML v5.2.12.710 Minecraft Forge 7.8.0.710 Optifine OptiFine_1.5.2_HD_U_D2 27 mods loaded, 27 mods active
    mcp{7.44} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    FML{5.2.12.710} [Forge Mod Loader] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Forge{7.8.0.710} [Minecraft Forge] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CodeChickenCore{0.8.7.1} [CodeChicken Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHCore{1.5.2.0} [CoFH Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ImmibisCore_InstalledAsCoreMod{55.1.6} [Immibis Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    NotEnoughItems{1.5.2.28} [Not Enough Items] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHNetwork{1.5.2.0} [CoFHNetwork] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHWorld{1.5.2.0} [CoFHWorld] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    GalacticraftCore{0.1.35} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-Mod-1.5.2 (1).jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    IC2{1.115.341-lf} [IndustrialCraft 2] (industrialcraft-2_1.115.341-lf.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    ImmibisCore{55.1.6} [Immibis Core] (immibis-core-55.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    mod_ReiMinimap{v3.3_05 [1.5.2]} [mod_ReiMinimap] ([1.5.2]ReiMinimap_v3.3_05.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    AdvancedSolarPanel{3.3.7} [Advanced Solar Panels] (Advanced-Solar-Panels-Addon-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Core{3.6.0} [BuildCraft] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Builders{3.6.0} [BC Builders] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Energy{3.6.0} [BC Energy] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Factory{3.6.0} [BC Factory] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Transport{3.6.0} [BC Transport] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BuildCraft|Silicon{3.6.0} [BC Silicon] (buildcraft-A-3.6.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    EE3{pre1h (build 16)} [Equivalent Exchange 3] (ee3-universal-pre1h-16.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    IronChest{5.2.4.391} [Iron Chest] (ironchest-universal-1.5.1-5.2.4.391.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    LiquidXP{55.1.6} [Liquid XP] (liquid-xp-55.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Mekanism{5.5.6} [Mekanism] (Mekanism-v5.5.6.64.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    MekanismGenerators{5.5.6} [MekanismGenerators] (MekanismGenerators-v5.5.6.64.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    MekanismTools{5.5.6} [MekanismTools] (MekanismTools-v5.5.6.64.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    OmniTools{3.1.2.0} [OmniTools] (Omni-Tools-1.5.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
```

Comment: It seems to be failing to load IC2; by doing some cross-referencing of error reports, I think you're trying to use a version that isn't compatible with the versions of Forge and FML you are using (still working on what the correct version would be; why does IC2 have to be the most confusing mod as far as versions go ever)

Comment: Or maybe not? Arg. IC2 is definitely causing issues here, but I can't really tell why it's causing issues.

Comment: Well I wouldn't suppose that is is Forge since I am using the latest one for Minecraft 1.5.2.

Comment: By the way I would like to thank you greatly for taking some of your time to help me figure this problem out. :)

Comment: @Unionhawk Figured out a solution yet?

Comment: It was Galactic Craft that was messing up for some reason

Comment: Yeah, I've seen reports that they're not exactly compatible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we no longer provide technical support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Galacticraft and IC2 are incompatible, unfortunately, at least in this particular version. Removing GalactiCraft should fix it (since you have several mods that require IC2).